# -bash: tsc: command not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, unix, npm, angular-cli

I am using MAC and trying to install TypeScript.
I install typescript using

> sudo npm install -g typescript

following is the result

```
Password:
/Users/<myuserid>/node/bin/tsc -> /Users/<myuserid>/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/Users/<myuserid>/node/bin/tsserver -> /Users/<myuserid>/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
/Users/<myuserid>/node/lib
└── typescript@2.5.2
```

Now when i try to use tsc i get error

> ```
> venu-mac:~ myuserid$ tsc
> -bash: tsc: command not found
> venu-mac:~ myuserid$
> ```

I do see tsc and tsserver exe files and following is tsc content

> $!/usr/bin/env node
>   require('../lib/tsc.js')

when I use following command from home it works

> ~ myuserid$ node/bin/tsc -v
>   Version 2.5.2

Same with Angular CLI installation. I use the following command to install Angualr via CLI:

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

There are no errors or warnings while installing Angular CLI, but whenever I use ng commands I get the following:

> -bash: ng: command not found

I tried removing/uninstalling all typescript and ng then reinstalling, upgrade  but it's been of no use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `~/node/bin` folder to the PATH variable

Advice: do not use that manuall nodejs install. Have a look at [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: I new i messed up something while installing node. Mac is new to me. Following is what i did and it worked. Thank you @Lazyexper. PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuserid/node/bin and it worked.